# Xamarin Forms bind view with viewmodel and viewmodel with service

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, binding

I have a question. Right now I have a mvvm based xamarin forms application. What I want to achieve is the following: Bind a view with a property in a viewmodel and use that property to reference a property in a service class. When the service property is changed, all views that bind to the service property from different viewmodels should be updated. How can I achieve this?

Code below is from one viewmodel, there are more viewmodel with properties referencing the service property.

```
    public string Signature
    {
        get => _activityStateService.Details.Signature.Autograph;
        set
        {
            _activityStateService.Details.Signature.Autograph = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Signature));
        }
    }
```

When one of the properties on the following objects changes, I want to notify the viewmodel(s) property that is referencing this object so that the views can be updated.

```
public class ActivityStateService : IActivityStateService
{
    public DriverActivity Details { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @M Yil If you want to use mvvm binding in Xamarin.forms, I suggest you can take a look the following article:[Xamarin.Forms Simple MVVM Binding Example](https://almirvuk.blogspot.com/2016/12/xamarinforms-simple-mvvm-binding-example.html), and you said that there are properties in viewmodel, these properties value came from service, if you want to update view when property changed, you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Answer (score 0):

View can have only one binding context. if you want to have multiple,it's impossible. But we have another way to solve this issue. First thing is you need to have this property (which you need to bind in multiple pages.) in your Viewmodelbase . The value of the property should be save to preference and get it from the preference. To get detail of preference please check Xamarin essentials

Comment: All views bind to 1 context because they each have a seperatie viewmodel. I really want to have a solution where the proerties in the viewmodels reference the same object, and when that object is changed, the views/viewmodels should be notified so that the binding can have effect. Your solution seems a little bit too much for what I want to achieve. Isn't there anoyher way to achieve this?

Comment: So you shoul write an expandable property in viewmodel and inthe view you can call the property as objectName.propertyName

Answer (score 0):

You could have another option instead have a service for this values you could use a local database to save the information for a page and when you go the other page retrieve the updated values this could be on the onappearing override.